# Ui material is not showing after build in mobile but showing in unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, material-ui, urp

I'm a Unity developer who recently upgraded from Unity 2021 to 2022.3.7f1. While I successfully tackled several errors during the transition, there's a particular issue I'm encountering. In the Unity editor, the material on a UI image displays as intended, but once I build the project for mobile, the material doesn't appear. I'm uncertain whether this is a bug or an error on my part. I would greatly appreciate some guidance on resolving this matter in a professional manner. Thank you.

I tried every thing changing shaders urp's not helping

[Material's settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myil3.png)
[Material's sprite settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmHrF.png)
[Image of material as a background of placeholders of cash, health,... on editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGOdm.jpg)
[Image of same in mobile where material background is invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akdZn.jpg)

Comment: can you do pictures ?

Comment: hi @BugFinder i have added images, please check and reply. Thanks

Comment: Is ShaderGraph involved in making the shaders/mats for the UI?

Comment: a question - how did you put the background in? have you changed the quality settings on your ide to see how it shows up under different qualities? in case for some reason it disappears with one?

Comment: @Nikaas no, I downloaded material from unity assets store.

Comment: @BugFinder i maked a ui panel on scene and assigned a material to that panel gameobject's image component. I don't know what ide is I am new to unity please help

Comment: integrated development environment (IDE)

Comment: Ok can you help me how to solve this error or bug ?

Comment: This question is not about Material UI, which is the React-specific implementation of Material Design. Please only use this tag for questions related to that specific library.